# hide command prompt while setting java home Python

Tags: java, python, stanford-parser

Currently I am working on PartOfSpeech(POS) tagging in Python using Stanford POStagger. I have set the java home

```
 java_path = "Path to java bin"
 os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
```

Below is my code

```
def getPOSandSentiment(sentence):
    path_to_model = 'Path/to/Tagger/wsj-0-18-left3words-distsim.tagger'
    path_to_jar = "path/to/stanford-postagger.jar"
    tagger=StanfordPOSTagger(path_to_model, path_to_jar)
    tagger.java_options='-mx2048m'
    posWords = tagger.tag(sentence.split())
    for words,pos in posWords: 
        print('Word : ',words)
        print('POS :', pos)
```

Everytime I pass a sentence, The java.exe command prompt gets popped up. Is there any way to hide that command prompt? I am using Anaconda3 and spyder IDE for python. Is there any way to set Java_Home in Spyder or Anaconda?
Thanks

Comment: use javaw, not java.

Comment: Where should I use javaw? Not clear. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Configure (or modify, if it's not directly configurable) StanfordPOSTagger to invoke javaw instead of java. Should be pretty straightforward, all you have to find is the invocation of the java VM and replace it with javaw.